# How to grep a value key before run my script?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, cgi

I need help with my bash script for my CGI in bash/html.

I have this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','

for arg
do
   echo "File :" $arg | cut -d'.' -f1
   echo "======================================================="
   echo ""
   while read FRAME RAM CPU1 CPU2
   do
      if [[ $FRAME != $PREV ]]
      then
         PREV=$FRAME
         echo "FRAME : $FRAME"
         echo -e "-----------------\n"
      fi
      echo -e "RAM : \t$RAM\n\
CPU 1 :\t$CPU1\n\
CPU 2 :\t$CPU2\n"
      echo ""
   done < "$arg"
done
```

This script helps me to analyze some csv files that looks like that :

```
MO2PPC07,12,0.1,1
MO2PPC07,8,0.1,1
O1PPC01,4,1.0,2
MO2PPC07,4,0.1,1
MO2PPC07,14,0.4,3
MO1PPC01,26,0.5,2
MO1PPC01,0.25,0.7,7
MO1PPC01,180,6.0,12
MO1PPC01,1,0.1,1
MO1PPC04,4,0.5,1
MO1PPC01,4,1.0,2
MO2PPC07,8,0.1,1
MO1PPC01,4,1.0,2
MO1PPC01,0.25,null,0
MO1PPC04,8,0.5,1
MO1PPC04,8,0.5,1
MO1PPC04,4,0.5,1
```

I have many files like this each with ~ 1000 lines.

My script allow to analyze all my csv files. But if I want to display only somes lines from a " Key value " like MO1PPC04 for exemple, I must use :

```
grep MO1PPC04
```

In my CGI, the user can choose the value that he want informations ( MO1PPC04, MO2PPC07, MO1PPC01 or many others... ). I'm able to recover the query strings to keep the value selected by the users with read a / echo $a :

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '
<html>
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="test/html"; charset=UTF-8">
                <title> CLF MONITORING </title>
                <h1> FRAME monitoring <font size=3> <a href="Index.sh">[ Index ]</a> </font> </h1>
                <hr size="4" color="blue">

        <style>
                         body{
                          background-color: #eff1f0;
                         }
        </style>

        </head>
<body>'

read a
echo $a

echo '</body>'
'</html>'
```

The idea is :

At the beginning of my script, I would like to keep only the lines in which we can find the value selected by the users with the command grep. After that, I would like that my script analyze only the line kept by the grep.

I don't know how to do this... Can you show me how ?

Thank you !

Comment: How is your script called ? Do you do something like `$ your_script.sh file.csv` ?

Comment: @Makmy : Why don't you simply test, whether FRAME equals one of the admitted values? Also, I don't understand the reference to `awk` in your posting, since you do not seem to use awk anywhere.

Comment: @Zelnes, yes ! absolutely  !

Comment: @user1934428 Sorry, just a mistake ! I don't us awk in this case. I change the title :)

Answer (score 0):

I considered that you were passing arguments to your script this way : `my_script.sh file1.csv,file2.csv`

First thing, you should separate each functionality in your script. This will help you determine how you can `grep`, or filter anything, from your input.

I suggest you can do something like this, were you could improve the filter (by parsing arguments and constructing something more sophisticated):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Called this way
# $ my_script.sh file1.csv,file2.csv

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','

filter_lines() {
    local file="$1"
    grep -E "^(MO2PPC07|MO1PPC01)" "$file"
}

process_line() {
    local FRAME RAM CPU1 CPU2 PREV
    while read FRAME RAM CPU1 CPU2
    do
        if [[ $FRAME != $PREV ]]
        then
            PREV=$FRAME
            echo "FRAME : $FRAME"
            echo -e "-----------------\n"
        fi
        echo -e "RAM : \t$RAM\n\
        CPU 1 :\t$CPU1\n\
        CPU 2 :\t$CPU2\n"
        echo ""
    done
}

process_files() {
    local arg="$1" i

    for i in $arg; do
        echo "File :" "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1
        echo "======================================================="
        echo ""
        filter_lines "$i" | process_line
    done
}

process_files "$1"
```